# JFrame doesn't show content

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to build a simple Swing application for inserting a file path in a GUI. (I know there's JOptionPane for this, but I want to check if the inserted path exists while the user is typing.)
I built a JFrame and added a JTextField and a JButton. It's just a part of another program, so it should pause the main program while it's active.
Now when I start the program, the JFrame itself builds up normally. But it doesn't load the content, it's not closable and when I try to resize the window, the whole program hangs up and I have to forcibly stop it from the IDE.
The program doesn't throw any Exceptions. I tried to insert some logs to test if the program hangs up at any point and I even looked after the `getSize()` of the components, but everything is as it should be - except that the content of the JFrame isn't visible on the screen. The strangest thing is that I have another method that's basically the same, just with other components - and it works perfectly.
I already searched for similar problems, but without success. Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputMethodListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test {
    
    public static String showFileDirInputDialog(String title, String dir) {
        boolean ready = false;
        String newFile = "";
        
        Thread windowThread = new Thread(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(600, 150);
            
            JTextField txt = new JTextField(dir);
            frame.getContentPane().add(txt, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            txt.addInputMethodListener(...); // check inserted path while typing
            
            JButton ok = new Button("OK");
            frame.getContentPane().add(ok, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            ok.addActionListener((e) -> {
                newFile = txt.getText();
                frame.dispose();
                ready = true;
            });
            
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }, "window thread");
        windowThread.start();
        
        while(!ready) {
            System.out.print(""); // do nothing while the window is active
        }
        windowThread.interrupt();
        return newFile;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"JFrame doesn't show content"* That code doesn't even compile. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *but I want to check if the inserted path exists while the user is typing* - how can you do this while the user is typing. The path won't exist until the user has "finished" typing at which time you try to verify the path. Maybe you should be using a `JFileChooser` to all a user to select a path.

Comment: Wow, that's funny. For the example code, I had to simplify a few things, but nothing that should affect the window's behavior. Now, as I run the example, it just works fine. So either I'm stupid or there's a bug in the swing package... anyway, I'm trying to reproduce the problem because the original code still doesn't work

Comment: Alright, so the problem actually seems to be different. Exactly the same code works when I call it directly from ```main()```, but not when I call it from an ActionListener. Is it possible that the ActionListeners are running in another thread that swing needs for displaying components?

Comment: *so the problem actually seems to be different* - which is why we always ask for an MRE. The MRE proves you understand the cause of the problem you are trying to solve. Code from any listener executes on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` The EDT is responsible for painting the GUI, so you probably have some other long running task that is preventing the GUI from repainting itself.  The long running task should execute on a different Thread. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Comment: Get rid of the while loop. Instead of using a JFrame, use a modal JDialog. The dialog will block automatically until the dialog is closed.

Comment: JDialog doesn't work. It instantly goes on with the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to @camickr, I've found a solution with `SwingWorker`:

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(150, 70);
        
        JButton btn = new JButton("Start");
        btn.addActionListener((e) -> {
            SwingWorker<String, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<>() {
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    return showFileInput("Insert file path");
                }
                
                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(get());
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            };
            worker.execute();
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(btn);
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    static String newPath = "";
    static boolean ready = false;
    
    static String showFileInput(String title) {
        Thread windowThread = new Thread(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(500, 70);
            
            JTextField txt = new JTextField("");
            frame.getContentPane().add(txt, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            
            JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
            okButton.addActionListener((e) -> {
                newPath = txt.getText();
                frame.dispose();
                ready = true;
            });
            frame.getContentPane().add(okButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
            
            Timer checkInputTimer = new Timer("check input thread");
            checkInputTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    File f = new File(txt.getText());
                    okButton.setEnabled(f.exists());
                }
            }, 0, 300);
            
            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    newPath = txt.getText();
                    frame.dispose();
                    ready = true;
                }
            });
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }, "window thread");
        windowThread.start();
        
        while(!ready) {
            System.out.print("");
        }
        windowThread.interrupt();
        return newPath;
    }
}
```